# Android TextToSpeech always fails to Run

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

For some reason `onInit()` always gets called with an error code despite the fact that I have verified that the required data files are available.

I have tried launching TTS(text-to-speech) code which has been copied in it's entirety from a tutorial and that does not work either

The following is my initialization code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == DATA_CHECK_SUCCESS) {

            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            }

            else {

                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {

        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            if(textToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        }
        else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent TTSIntent = new Intent();
        TTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(TTSIntent, DATA_CHECK_SUCCESS);

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is an issue in the Android emulator provided with Android studio as it does not provide TTS

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue before with Speech to Text, the problem was that the Google app installed on the device was disabled or does not have the microphone permission.

Check if this helps with your issue.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but may I advise that you use the comments to troubleshoot problems and then answers to provide full answers

Comment: Sadly I still don't have enough reputation to comment, I wanted to see if my answer is helpful, and if it was not I will be removing it.